# Best way to move several files on the same server

Tags: debian, file-server

I find myself with a lot of files and folders that are not structured well. If they were on a USB  drive, I could just move them using my laptop. Unfortunately they are on two raid1 hard drives on a server. Using `cp` and `rsync` is a real pain.

Is anyone aware of some sort of (web?) user interface that allows me to easily move files and folders conveniently?

Options I have tried and discarded:

- Sprut.io: seems to do the job perfectly but it's totally unreliable and seems quite insecure (stores the password in plain text in the logs lol)
- RDP using a light XFCE interface: heavy and need of a stable connection

Running the system on a VM with Debian 10 fyi

**EDIT: it is inconvenient to use mv or rsync or anything over the terminal as many files have to be selected and moved**

Comment: Based on your description I don't understand what the problem of the server is. Depending on how the server is configured it provides different interfaces for accessing and managing data, some are identical to data stored locally. It is unclear why you especially mention `cp` and `rsync` as the question is about moving (so why not `mv`?). Please edit your question and explain what interfaces the server provides, how much permissions you have on that server (can you install software).

Comment: Question edited with some clarification.